# How to get all the values as keyname = keyvalue from a json out put?

Tags: java, json, spring

I am a beginner in json programming. I've searched a lot but could not find a suitable solution to get the dynamic key of a JSON output. So i am asking this question.
I have a jsonObject as below:

```
jsonObj = {"A":"A","C":"C","D":"D","B ":"B"}
```

All the keys are dynamic. I've got many solution where values were retrieved by `jsonObj.getString("keyname");`But in my case as the keys are all dynamic so i can not put a specific key name in `jsonObj.getString("keyname")`.
How to get all the values as `keyname = keyvalue`? I am using java spring framework.
suppose my json is: `{"Tea": "Sugar", "Milj ": "jikk", "Paqjj": "qouta", "Coffee": "Melt"}`But i got this output:`keys in the json are Sugar` My expected output is :`key is Tea and value of Tea is Sugar`.

Comment: which JSON library do you use?

Comment: @Henry org.json

Comment: The JavaDoc has all the details: https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code to get the keys and values :

```
 JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseStr)
    Iterator<String> keys = response.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
              String key = keys.next();
              String value = response.getString(key);
       }
```